# What is ment by attaching an entity to a context?

Tags: entity-framework-5, state

I've learned that entities are classes that represent the tables inside a database schema. But on this link they speak of an entity being tracked (attached) by the context

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

```
Added: the entity is being tracked by the context...
```

Do they speak of the objects/instances of entity's (so the classes) getting tracked by Entity Framework? Or literally the entity itself? I'm confused.

In one of my webapplications I am using this code, does it say all instances of `FinalStudyDecision` are in the modified state, or just the object `fsd`?

```
context.FinalStudyDecisions.Attach(fsd);
context.Entry(fsd).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Or does this code just do it for one single object?

```
ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(fsd, EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: I just found out that DBContext and ObjectContexts are two different ways of connecting to EF. I'm doing some research about them right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an entity is attached to a context, the context "knows" the object and starts tracking its changes.

Normally, an entity is attached to a context when it is fetched from the database, e.g. by `context.FinalStudyDecisions.Single(x => x.Id == 1)` (if there is an item with Id == 1 of course).

But if you've got an existing `FinalStudyDecisions` that is not known by a context you can use the `Attach` method to make it known. This usually happens when an object is serialized to and subsequently deserialized from a web client.

If you attach an object to a context its state (`EntityState`) is `Unchanged`, so often you will change its state to `Modified` when you receive it back from a web client. This will trigger EF to store the object when `SaveChanges` is called.

Both

```cs
// DbContext API
context.Entry(fsd).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

and

```cs
// ObjectContext API
ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(fsd, EntityState.Modified);
```

only change the state of the `fsd` object.

**Important:** if you **`Add`** an object to a context, either by setting its state `Added` or by adding it to a `DbSet` (or `ObjectSet`), not only `fsd` but also all its child objects are changed to `Added`.

Comment: Thanks dude, couldn't have asked for a better answer.